# Opening a web page makes two identical requests, but the second one with "Accept: image/webp,*/*" header

Tags: nginx, proxy, request, http2, webp

I have an nginx proxy node and an nginx upstream node. When I open the page in a browser, the original request is then duplicated but uses a different `Accept: image/webp,*/*` header.

It's running behind Cloudflare proxy with `Development mode ON` so this should make no difference. I don't see any reason why it's doing it.

First request: `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`

Second request: `Accept: image/webp,*/*`

Please see highlighted rows on the screenshot.

[image: Accept: image/webp,*/*]

Comment: Wild guess, you have something like `<img src="">` somewhere in your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your page source you have this:

```
<div class="logo-this-pub" style="background-image: url('')">
```

This is exactly the cause of this request. As I could see you're using a WordPress. Usually it is a result of some shortcode rendering where an id of non-existent WordPress media library element is used (this could occur when you use media library element while composing the page and delete it later). So you need to check what shortcode is rendered to this HTML code and fix it.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot. This thing was driving me nuts and I already played for like half a day with nginx config :)